# Connect to OpenStack instance via the internet through the router

Tags: networking, openstack, openstack-neutron

I've recently found out that the external network for our OpenStack (Ocata) setup has maxed out on the available IP addresses in its allocation table. In fact, it has over-allocated with -9 free IPs. So, to manage the limited IP addresses, is it possible to access an instance in a project directly from an external network (internet) via the project's router? This way only a single IP address needs to be allocated per project instead of allocating to multiple instances per project.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be NO, but there are couple of workarounds that came to my mind (not that they will be good, but they will work).

1. In case any instance in your private network has floatingIP, you can use that host as a jump-host (bastion-host) to SSH into the target host. This also brings the benefits of port forwarding/SSH tunneling to the table if you want to access to some other port.
2. You can always access to any host on private networks through qdhcp or qrouter namespace from the network node
   ip netns exec qdhcp-XXXXXXX ssh user@internal-IP

Comment: Does this mean that a router may not be necessary for any project if an instance has been allocated with a floating IP?

Comment: Quite the opposite, you always need a router prior to associating a floating IP. In neutron a router actually does a NAT for all instances with private IP, and the difference with  floating IP is that the router does a source & destination NAT, completely one to one (private IP <=> floating IP).

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly: The router would still need an external gateway address from the external network, then connected to the private network. Then, an instance connected to the private network with a floating IP (from the external network) can be used as like a "head node" or landing server to access the other servers. Is that right? If so, then the external network would need to allocate 2 IPs — the router's external gateway and the server's floating IP.

Comment: Yep. google bastion host, this will help you in this scenario.